# Sum of word scores for a column containing lists of words

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a words column:

```
> print(df['words'])
0       [awww, thats, bummer, shoulda, got, david, car...   
1       [upset, that, he, cant, update, his, facebook,...   
2       [dived, many, time, ball, managed, save, rest,...   
3       [whole, body, feel, itchy, like, it, on, fire]   
4       [no, it, not, behaving, at, all, im, mad, why,...   
5       [not, whole, crew]
```

and another sentiment column for the "sentiment" value of each word:

```
> print(sentiment) 
           abandon  -2
0        abandoned  -2
1         abandons  -2
2         abducted  -2
3        abduction  -2
4       abductions  -2
5            abhor  -3
6         abhorred  -3
7        abhorrent  -3
8           abhors  -3
9        abilities   2
...
```

For each row of words in `df['words']` I want to sum up their respective sentiment values. For words not present in sentiment, equate to 0.

This is what I have so far:

```
df['sentiment_value'] = Sum(df['words'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x+x for x in sentiment))
```

expected result

```
print(df['sentiment_value'])
0        -5   
1         2   
2        15  
3        -6   
4        -8   
...
```

Comment: It looks like you have incorrectly loaded `sentiment` with the first data row as the header.

Comment: Hi, do you mind clarifying what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the scores a Series, with the word as the label:

```
In [11]: s  # e.g. sentiment.set_index("word")["score"]
Out[11]:
abandon     -2
abandoned   -2
abandons    -2
abducted    -2
abduction   -2
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Then you can look up a list's score:

```
In [12]: s.loc[["abandon", "abducted"]].sum()
Out[12]: -4
```

So the apply would be:

```
df['words'].apply(lambda ls: s.loc[ls])
```

---

If you need to support missing words (not in s) you can use reindex:

```
In [21]: s.reindex(["abandon", "abducted", "missing_word"]).sum()
Out[21]: -4.0

df['words'].apply(lambda ls: s.reindex(ls))
```

Answer (score 0):

if Second column has value in string  then you need to filter data first with by converting 
column into two column

```
df['Sentiment'],df['Sentiment_value']=df.sentiment.str.split(" ")
```

then you can find index of sentiment from sentiment column and get value from sentiment_value column